# jute.maxbuffer affects only incoming traffic

Tags: apache-zookeeper, vert.x

Does this value only affect incoming traffic? If i set this value to say 4MB on zookeeper server as well as zookeeper client and I start my client, will I still get data > 4MB when I do a request for a path `/abc/asyncMultiMap/subs`.  If `/subs` has data greater than 4MB is the server going to break it up in chunks <= 4MB and send it in pieces to the client?

I am using zookeeper 3.4.6 on both client (via vertx-zookeeper) and server.  I see errors on clients where it complains that packet length is greater than 4MB.

```
java.io.IOException: Packet len4194374 is out of range!
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket.readLength(ClientCnxnSocket.java:112) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no chunking in the response.

This is a server-side setting.  You will get this error if the entirety of the response is greater than the `jute.maxbuffer` setting.  This response limit includes the list of children of znodes as well so even if `subs` does not have a lot of data but has enough children such that their length of their paths exceeds the max buffer size you will get the error.

Answer (score 1):

"This is a server-side setting"
This statement is incorrect, jute.maxbuffer is evaluated on client as well by Record implementing classes that receive InputArchive. Each time a field is read and stored into an InputArchive the value is checked against jute.maxbuffer. Eg ClientCnxnSocket.readConnectResult

I investigated it in ZK 3.4